Please help me understand why a given \noexpand is required, and if it's possible to move it elsewhere
I am using the listofitems package to feed macros with an arbitrary number of arguments, which are being picked apart by the package's \readlist and \foreachitem functions. I managed to finally get it to work -- great success! -- but I don't understand why, so I fear it still may explode during future use.
Here is the smallest sample I can extract from my code:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%=============================[ action ]

\newcommand{\modelAction}[1]{
    \setsepchar{--next condition--}
    \readlist*\actionConditionsList{#1}
    \begin{itemize}[label=!]
    \foreachitem \actionCondition \in \actionConditionsList{
        \item \actionCondition
    }
    \end{itemize}
}

%====================[ special actions ]

\newcommand{\dataCardSpecialActions}[1]{
    \setsepchar{--next action--}
    \readlist*\specialActions{#1}
    \foreachitem \sAction \in \specialActions{
        \setsepchar{::}
        \readlist*\actionArgs{\sAction}
        \ExpandArgs{e}\modelAction{\actionArgs[1]}
    }
}

%==========================[ data card ]

\newcommand{\dataCard}[1]{
    \dataCardSpecialActions{#1}
}

%==================================================================[ Document ]

\begin{document}

\dataCard{
    WARN 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    --next condition--
    WARN 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod \noexpand\textbf{tempor} incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}

\end{document}

This successfully produces the desired output:

However, the issue is the \noexpand\textbf{tempor} in the last argument of the top-level call of the \dataCard macro:

The issue is two-fold:

If you remove the \noexpand, the compilation produces a couple of errors that I cannot follow.
However, if you remove the \noexpand AND the \textbf around "tempor", then the compilation runs through without issue.

Thus I have the following two questions, please:

Why is the \noexpand needed here?
Can the \noexpand be moved anywhere else in the call stack of macros, so that the top-level call of the \dataCard macro may receive only plain text + formatting, without requiring any special treatment to successfully run through the series of the underlying macros?

Thank you for your consideration :)
Related [added by cfr]:

When using listofitems to read a nested list to fill a table, \readlist seems to only read the last entry
listofitems delimiter no longer recognized after passing through \readlist


I guess the intention of the line
\ExpandArgs{e}\modelAction{\actionArgs[1]}

is to call \modelAction with whatever is stored in \actionArgs[1], not with \actionArgs[1] itself. However, \ExpandArgs does not stop at expanding \actionArgs[1] when it reaches its contents, but expands the contents as well. By adding \noexpand to \textbf, you manually prevent this extra expansion.
To avoid the total expansion and the explicit adding of \noexpand, replace the line by the lengthy expression
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\modelAction
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
{\actionArgs[1]}%

This sequence expands \actionArgs[1] only twice; the result corresponds to the original contents of \actionArgs[1].
As a side note, don't be so generous with spurious spaces within macro definitions, as they might affect the output. See the comment signs in the code below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%=============================[ action ]

\newcommand{\modelAction}[1]{%
    \setsepchar{--next condition--}%
    \readlist*\actionConditionsList{#1}%
    \begin{itemize}[label=!]%
    \foreachitem \actionCondition \in \actionConditionsList{%
        \item \actionCondition
    }%
    \end{itemize}%
}

%====================[ special actions ]

\newcommand{\dataCardSpecialActions}[1]{%
    \setsepchar{--next action--}%
    \readlist*\specialActions{#1}%
    \foreachitem \sAction \in \specialActions{%
        \setsepchar{::}%
        \readlist*\actionArgs{\sAction}%
%        \ExpandArgs{e}\modelAction{\actionArgs[1]}
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \modelAction
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        {\actionArgs[1]}%
    }%
}

%==========================[ data card ]

\newcommand{\dataCard}[1]{%
    \dataCardSpecialActions{#1}%
}

%==================================================================[ Document ]

\begin{document}

\dataCard{
    WARN 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    --next condition--
    WARN 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod \textbf{tempor} incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
}

\end{document}


Ah, thank you! I suspected one of those \expandafter constructs would be the solution, which I was hoping to being able to avoid using \ExpandArgs. Oh well!
Also thanks for the additional comment on the white spaces! This was already pointed out to me in previous questions (this is the third follow-up question to the same element), and doing a pass through the whole document to rectify this has been added to the document's todo list :)

@Fabian It was not at all clear that \expandafter can do the trick. Thanks to the author of the package, the first round of expansion yields something that can be expanded a second time. The documentation of the package mentioned this property and made me try it.
